# setImageDrawble outside onCreate

Tags: android

I have drawer layout , and at the top there is an ImageView 
inside DrawerFragment class ,
when I tried to setImageDrawble form onCreate it work 
but when I try to do this method outside onCreat I have ( NUllPointException )
 this is onCreate method

```
RecyclerView recyclerView ;
MyAdapter adapter;
View view ;
ImageView drawerPic ; 
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle ;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_fragmnet_layout,null,false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),setItems());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    drawerPic = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    drawerPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);


    return  view ;

}
```

when I try to do

```
        drawerPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
```

outside onCreat  (from another method )
or when I declare object form this class then do another method which setImageResource inside it

,, I have this error

> 03-22 21:01:30.525 29538-29538/maysara.maysara_.com.materialdesignpro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{maysara.maysara_.com.materialdesignpro/maysara.maysara_.com.materialdesignpro.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:167)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5405)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                               at maysara.maysara_.com.materialdesignpro.DrawerFragment.setUp(DrawerFragment.java:55)
>                                                                                               at maysara.maysara_.com.materialdesignpro.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1151)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:167) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5405) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

why this is happened ?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) ,you can figure out that onAttach() and onCreate() are called before you view is created and if you call your ***drawerPic*** in these two method or the methods which are called before onCreateView() you will get NullPointerException because it is not initialized.

Try using it in methods that are called after onCreateView()

Comment: the problem that I cant use findViewById() out side onCreat()
,,, I can do inflation only in onCreate as u see in my code

Comment: 1. declare 'private View myview' at class level

2. view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_fragmnet_layout,null,false);
    myview=view;

3. use myview.findViewById() anywhere you want

Comment: I did ,, and the same problem appeared

Comment: You cannot set any UI element until its view is inflated.

Comment: when I make the View which I inflated as class member ( look at my code above ) 
then use it again ,,it should work 
but it doesn't ,,, and I am here to know why this is happened